# Why does directory not forward to index.html but instead to 403 error

Tags: .htaccess, directory, parent-child

I have a website with a main directory and a child directory. When I enter `www.example.com` it properly goes to the `index.html` (`www.example.com/index.html`) but when I do `www.example.com/childdirectory` it forwards me to 403 instead of `www.example.com/childdirectory/index.html`. Why does it do this and how do I fix this?

I already tried putting this code in my `.htaccess` but it didn't work:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Comment: "it properly goes to the index.html (`www.example.com/index.html`)" - Presumably it doesn't actually redirect you? You don't see `index.html` in the address bar? Do you have any other directives in the `.htaccess` file? Do you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/childdirectory`? When you request `/childdirectory` to you not first see a 301 redirect to `/childdirectory/` (with a trailing slash)? "putting this in my htaccess" - To clarify, the filename needs a dot prefix.

Comment: Could be due to a combination of `DirectorySlash off` and `Options -Indexes`. The latter forbids the directory listing and returns a 403, if no index document is available. And the former disables the automatic redirect from `/childdirectory` to `/childdirectory/`, so that an existing index document won't be used.

Comment: MrWhite. 1. yes it doesnt actually redirect me, 2. yes i dont see index.html in address bar. 3. yes i have more code in my .htaccess, this code is just www and ssl redirects and I also have a redirect that if you enter in url example.com/home it redirects you to example.com. 4. I don't have another .htaccess in childdirectory, 5. it sends me to 403 trailing slash or not